# Why this code is returning undefined?

Tags: javascript, recursion, array-reverse

```
var rarr = [];
var reverseArray = function(arr) {
  if(arr[0]) {
     rarr.push(arr[arr.length-1]);
     arr.pop();
     reverseArray(arr);
  } else {
    return rarr;
  }
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```

While debugging value of rarr is ['C','B','A'] at the end, instead it is returning undefined. Thanks in advance.

Comment: notwithstanding the `return` bug in the answers given so far, testing `arr[0]` to get loop termination is _horrible_ - it'll break if any element of your array holds a falsey value (e.g. zero)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While debugging value of rarr is ['C','B','A'] at the end, instead it
>   is returning undefined

You are not returning the value that will be returned by recursive calls

replace

```
reverseArray(arr);
```

with

```
return reverseArray(arr);
```

Or simply

```
console.log(["A", "B", "C"].reverse());
```

Comment: Oops.. missed it.. Thanks. Any other optimized way that you can suggest?

Comment: @kamalkokne just `["A", "B", "C"].reverse()`

Comment: reverse() is perfect but I was looking for optimized solution w/o reverse method. Thanks

Comment: @kamalkokne something like `var reverseArray = function(arr) {
  var rarr = [];
  while(arr.length > 0 )
  { 
    rarr.push(arr.pop()); 
  }
  return rarr;
}` without recursion.

Answer (score 1):

you forgot a return in your if... try this:

```
var rarr = [];
var reverseArray = function(arr) {
  if(arr[0]) {
     rarr.push(arr[arr.length-1]);
     arr.pop();
     return reverseArray(arr);
  } else {
    return rarr;
  }
}

console.log(reverseArray(["A", "B", "C"]));
```